# How to avoid WebKit contentEditable copy-paste resulting in unwanted CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, copy-paste, contenteditable

I have a `<div>` that has `contentEditable="true"`.

When I **copy-paste content within the editable div**, the pasted text gets wrapped into a lot of unwanted CSS.

For example, this:
`<p>text text</p>`
becomes:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; outline-width: 0px; outline-style: initial; outline-color: initial; font-size: 17px; vertical-align: baseline; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: transparent; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; ">text text</p>
```

I understand the browser (Google Chrome in the current case) tries to be smart and all, but what I end up is completely irrelevant and unwanted CSS.

Is there any way to tell the WebKit-based browser **not** to generate this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, plus the problem that every browser creates different HTML. So I wrote a JavaScript port of the [Sanitize](http://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) library: [Sanitize.js](http://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js)

Sanitize.js is a whitelist-based HTML sanitizer written in JavaScript. Given a list of acceptable elements and attributes, Sanitize.js will remove all unacceptable HTML from a DOM node.

Have a look at the example, where I capture the `paste` event and process the HTML afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up using a similar sanitizer in the back-end (using PHP Tidy) to remove unwanted markup before storing the input in the database.

Comment: Few years gone by and I have moved away from PHP Tidy. In fact, I am using the exact same library (Sanitize.js) now and highly recommend it! Works nicely with JSDom on NodeJS as well.

Comment: Your Sanitize library is awesome! Thanks for that mate.