# simple html editor and get html content using div or textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Trying to create a simple html editor.

```js
$('#edit').on('input', function(e){
 console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```css
.edit{
background:gold;
min-height:140px;
font-size:1.6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='edit' id='edit' contenteditable></div>
```

type this inside the div `edit`:

```
lorem
ipsum
```

then place the cursor at the end of `lorem` - and press `spacebar` and `del` on keyboard to get this:

`lorem ipsum`

and you'll see the problem - `ipsum` has much larger font size then `lorem`.

That's the first question - how to avoid this?

My second try was using `textarea` instead of contenteditable div but in that case I cannot use `document.execCommand` to change some text to be `bold` etc.

So what is the way to set html tags inside `textarea` like it's done here on `stackoverflow`, or on `wordpress` sites and so on?

My final goal is to provide a simple editor with just a a few commands - `bold, italic and align` Users should be able to type and style the text, and click on a button should get the html content.

Any help?

Comment: https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480

Comment: Don;t use contenteditable. Choose an existing markup like Markdown or Pug and utilize a preexisting library to convert the input to HTML. For ex. https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked

Comment: @robinsax, - ` and utilize a preexisting library to convert the input to HTML` - any example, pls

Comment: `contentEditable` is more like a WYSINWYE (What You See Is Not What You Expect). I can't reproduce your issue with Firefox, though.

Comment: @Teemu, try on chrome, pls

Comment: Indeed, Chrome and Opera added a `<span style="font-size: 1.6em;">` element, Firefox and Edge didn't, neither did IE11.

Comment: Yes, Chrome adds span tags for some reason, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243432/prevent-contenteditable-mode-from-creating-span-tags)

Comment: So, the span within a div, both with relative font sizes set.  If you changed your font from 1.6em to 1.6rem, it should not get bigger.

Comment: @qadenza I did include an example... `marked` is a markdown to HTML converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by many angry developers, `contenteditable` is indeed terrible - don't expect anything great, but let's try to make do anyway.

By wrapping the editable div inside another div and applying the CSS font to this wrapper, the text shall not get bigger when doing the process described in the question. The HTML is still ugly (useless span tags with 1em of font size), but the text content is acceptable.

```js
const editable = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]');

editable.onkeyup = () => {
  document.querySelector('#html-log').innerText = editable.innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('#text-log').innerText = JSON.stringify(editable.innerText);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
div[contenteditable] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div contenteditable></div>
</div>

<h3>HTML content</h3>
<pre id="html-log"></pre>

<h3>Text content</h3>
<pre id="text-log"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [`.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands)

Try loading the first parameter dynamically by assigning the `#id` of each `<button>` to match a command.

> ```
> <button id="bold">B</button>
> ...
> ... var ID = this.id;
> return document.execCommand(ID, false, null)
> ```

---

### Demo

```js
$('#WYSINWYE').on('submit', function() {
  return false;
});
$('#edit').focus();
$('#edit').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#view').html($(this).text());
});
$('#ctrl button').on('click', function() {
  var ID = this.id;
  if (ID === 'HTML') {
    $('#view').slideToggle('750')
    return;
  }
  return document.execCommand(ID, false, null);
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  font: 400 16px/1.25 Arial;
}

#view {
  background: gold;
  min-height: 100px;
  font: inherit;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

#ctrl {
  height: 20px;
}

#edit {
  font: inherit;
  font-family: Consolas;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  width: 36px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

b:hover,
button:hover {
  color: rgba(205, 121, 0, 0.8);
}

#HTML {
  float: right
}

#ctrl button:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

#ctrl button:nth-of-type(6) {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

#ctrl button:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id='WYSINWYE'>
  <fieldset id='view' class='text' contenteditable='false' style='display:none'>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id='ctrl'>
    <button id='bold' class="fas fa-bold"></button>
    <button id='italic' class="fas fa-italic"></button>
    <button id='underline' class="fas fa-underline"></button>
    <b>|</b>
    <button id='justifyLeft' class="fas fa-align-left"></button>
    <button id='justifyCenter' class="fas fa-align-center"></button>
    <button id='justifyRight' class="fas fa-align-right"></button>
    <button id='HTML' class="fas fa-code"></button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id='edit' class='text' contenteditable='true'>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```